# MSTest Data Driven Test Inline Data

Tags: c#, unit-testing

**Background**:

Didn't what to have to reference bulky 3rd party lib for inline data driven tests and wanted to use standard MS testing framework.

Created helper `InlineDataDrivenTest` to provide a workaround for this limitation.

**Usage**

```
[TestClass]
public class DataDrivenTests : MiscUnitTests {

    [TestMethod]
    public void Should_Do_Data_Driven_Test() {
        //Arrange 
        var source = new TestDataSource();
        var test = InlineDataDrivenTest.Create(source);
        test.Setup(c => c.TestAdd(0, 0, 0));
        //Act
        test.Run();
        //Assert
        var summary = test.GetResult();
        Assert.IsTrue(summary.Succeeded, summary.Message);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Should_Do_Data_Driven_Test_And_Fail() {
        //Arrange 
        var target = new TestDataSource();
        var test = InlineDataDrivenTest
            .Create(target)
            .Setup(m => m.TestSubtract(0, 0, 0));
        //Act
        test.Run();
        //Assert
        var summary = test.GetResult();
        Assert.IsTrue(summary.Failed == 1, summary.Message);
    }


    public class TestDataSource {

        [DataDrivenTestMethod]
        [DataRow(1, 2, 3)]
        [DataRow(4, 5, 9)]
        public void TestAdd(int a, int b, int expected) {
            Calculator c = new Calculator();
            int actual = c.Add(a, b);
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }

        [DataDrivenTestMethod]
        [DataRow(4, 2, 2)]
        [DataRow(4, 1, 1, DisplayName = "Should fail for demo purposes")]
        public void TestSubtract(int a, int b, int expected) {
            Calculator c = new Calculator();
            int actual = c.Subtract(a, b);
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }

    }

    public class Calculator {

        public int Add(int a, int b) {
            return a + b;
        }

        public int Subtract(int a, int b) {
            return a - b;
        }
    }
}
```

Thoughts and feed back on code.

This solves the immediate need but I'm looking to improve on current model.

Comment: I'd be interesting in seeing the implementation of your attributes.

Comment: They are just simple custom classes derived from `System.Attribute` used to provide metadata. At runtime during testing the target class is inspected using reflection for those attributes then tagged methods are invoked with provided data and results aggregated.

Comment: nice. How can I try this ?